# Feature Extraction of a binary image

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-extraction

i am doing OCR project using c++ and opencv. I have some black and white images of separated handwritten characters. I want to extract unique features from those images in order to classify them using LIBSVM. can any one tell me what are the suitable algorithms for feature extraction in opencv?

Comment: If you are doing OCR, then firstly don't say black and white images. For the features, you must classify your requirements, before fed to the classifier. Nevertheless, not more and more features helps your accuracy, instead the system be messy. So, firstly you came with the conclusion that what features (eg: Geometric shapes,orientation etc)   suits your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can read [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/common_interfaces_for_feature_detection_and_descriptor_extraction.html). And try [this](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/matcher_simple.cpp?rev=3203).

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Search within older releases or google it. e.g. http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn_org/cpp/common_interfaces_for_feature_detection_and_descriptor_extraction.html